# Is it a bad practice to throw an exception in the plugin?

Tags: plugin, exception, function

Let's say one wants to use a `before` plugin. Also let's say under a certain circumstance it is impossible to do so, therefore we want to throw an exception.

However it doesn't feel right to do so; but I am unable to explain it to myself why so. Maybe it is because when one uses the function and it suppose to work correctly (without the plugin) suddenly breaks because of the plugin; feels like a function definitely should work without the plugin, therefore if it does, then the plugin has no right to break it.

It also can be viewed as if the original method signature states it doesn't throw any exceptions and here, boom, a plugin breaks that "signature" by throwing one. Then I guess the oppposite should apply too - if the original function has an exception throw annotaation then we are allowed to throw an exception in the plugin as well.

Furthermore, I am aware that a plugin might not be the best tool if the goal is to build something that is not related to the original method directly - an event observer should be considered; whereas plugin is more like a tool allowing to modify arguments or tweak the original behaviour slightly; but even then sometimes it might be impossible to do so, therefore an exception throw can be used. Or can't it?

I can't really fully grasp it, but I hope you got an idea. Please let me know about the good practice here (if there is any at all). Perhaps I am missing a point or two, and if one can point one/them out to me, that would help me a lot.

Comment: I'm struggling a bit to understand what you mean to say with one of your opening statements "Also let's say under a certain circumstance it is impossible to do so [...]" - in other words, do you mean to say that your `beforeOriginalFunc` function does *something* and (based on some condition) comes to the conclusion that `originalFunc` is now not supposed to be executed anymore?

Comment: No. I mean that if a task that is suppose to be done in the `beforeOriginalFunc` fails to be performed (for example we need to divide, and a zero was passed)